# Can you uniquely define a tangent line at a point for a 3D csurve?

Tags: geometry, derivatives

Let f be a function of the form: $x=f_x(t); y=f_y(t);\text{ and }z=f_z(t)$. Does the derivative set of the 3 functions mean the tangent at a point on the curve of f?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, by heuristics and thereafter by definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(f_x(t),f_y(t),f_z(t))$ denotes the position of an object in space at time $t$, then $\langle f'_x(t),f'_y(t),f'_z(t)\rangle$ returns the rate of change of the object with respect to time, i.e. velocity.  Thus, it's a vector pointing in  the direction of motion.

For example, if the functions
$$(f_x(t),f_y(t),f_z(t)) = (t\cos(t), t\sin(t), t),$$
parametrize a helix with growing diameter. The motion along this curve with its velocity vector looks like so:

[image]